How to properly scroll to an Element in VueJS when navigating back from a route, using an offset?
I am fighting with the Vue Router (Version 4.2 in my case). I want to achieve that when the user returns from navigation to another route, the original vertical position is restored.
  const router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
      if (from.hash) {
        console.log('Scroll to Hash', from.hash);

        return {
          el: from.hash,
          behavior: 'smooth',
          offset: { x: 0, y: 160 },
        };
      } else if (savedPosition) {
        console.log('Saved Position', savedPosition);
        return savedPosition;

Using this configuration, I am able to include a hash in my routes to ensure that when the user returns, the original position is partially restored. The issue is that the browser scrolls down to the element, but it scrolls too far, leaving the actual element hidden above the top of the view.
However, although the official documentation mentions a parameter for applying an offset, it seems to be ignored.
I've tried various values for the Y-axis, but none seem to have any effect.
I reviewed the repository for Vue Router v4.2, and it appears that the offset parameter has been removed.
Is there an alternative available?
The corresponding types in the source code of the router confirm that there is no longer a parameter called "offset." Without it, the scrolling experience is severely compromised.
Original code from the vue-router 4.2:
declare type ScrollPosition = ScrollPositionCoordinates | ScrollPositionElement;

/**
 * Scroll position similar to
 * {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions | `ScrollToOptions`}.
 * Note that not all browsers support `behavior`.
 */
declare type ScrollPositionCoordinates = {
    behavior?: ScrollOptions['behavior'];
    left?: number;
    top?: number;
};

declare interface ScrollPositionElement extends ScrollToOptions {
    /**
     * A valid CSS selector. Note some characters must be escaped in id selectors (https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).
     * @example
     * Here are a few examples:
     *
     * - `.title`
     * - `.content:first-child`
     * - `#marker`
     * - `#marker\~with\~symbols`
     * - `#marker.with.dot`: selects `class="with dot" id="marker"`, not `id="marker.with.dot"`
     *
     */
    el: string | Element;
}


According to this GitHub issue from 3 years ago, we have to distinguish between Safari and Chrome and have to use both: top and offset
    return {
      el: from.hash,
      behavior: 'smooth',
      top: 100,
      offset: { x: 0, y: 100 },

Both properties can not be found in the type-definition in the official repository, but it seems to work properly.
